# mysql select statement. why does it return 6 of the same record

Tags: mysql, sql

When I make this sql statement I get 6 of the same record returned. So if I expect to get 2 records returned, I get six of each record back so that is 12 in total.

```
SELECT 
ce2.* 
FROM customerentry ce, customerentrytrace cet, customerentry ce2 
WHERE ce.accountid = 1 
AND ce.companyid = 1 
AND ce.accountid=cet.accountid 
AND ce.accountid=ce2.accountid 
AND ce.companyid=cet.companyid 
AND ce.companyid=ce2.companyid 
AND cet.documentno = '2012Faktura1' 
AND cet.documenttype = 1 
AND ce2.documentno = cet.offsetdocumentno 
AND ce2.documenttype = cet.offsetdocumenttype 
ORDER BY created;
```

I know that I can solve it by adding `distinct`, but I would like to know why I get 6 of the same record returned. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Probably because there are six matching rows in the database. Could you post a sample of the database with the result you expect and the real result?

Comment: Please provide the some more detail about tables and output.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have no idea about your table structure probably there are some columns that are related 1 to n items and you haven't handled them in the `WHERE` section of your query.

As an extra measure you can focus on your data needs and add a `GROUP BY` section before your `ORDER` section.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an INNER JOIN, so for example there are two entries in table cet matching your where clause for combining table ce and cet, giving you 2 entries/entry of table ce.

Thinking this further you can see that if there are 3 entries in table ce2 matching the where clause for combining table cet and ce2 you get 3 entries/entry of table cet.

Which makes 6 entries per entry of table ce in total, giving you 12 entries in total even if you have only 2 entries in table ce.

So think again about what join could be the right for your desired solution.

Here a link for some more explanation: [Short explanation of joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be because you have not properly joined tables. Please read about `JOIN`

```
SELECT ce2.* 
FROM customerentry ce INNER JOIN customerentrytrace cet ON ce.accountid=cet.accountid AND ce.companyid=cet.companyid, 

INNER JOIN customerentry ce2 ON ce.accountid=ce2.accountid AND ce.companyid=ce2.companyid AND ce2.documentno = cet.offsetdocumentno AND ce2.documenttype = cet.offsetdocumenttype 

WHERE ce.accountid = 1 
    AND ce.companyid = 1 
    AND cet.documentno = '2012Faktura1' 
    AND cet.documenttype = 1 

ORDER BY created;
```